# How to enable/disable TCP DELAYED ACK parameter on SUSE linux?

Tags: tcp

I want to disable TCP DELAYED ACK parameter on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server for some performance tuning operations.

I have used  **sysctl**  command but it does not list this parameter.
also in [SUSE Knowledge Base Docs](https://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=10068360) it is mentioned that  **"SET TCP DELAYED ACK = OFF"** but not how to set it.

Can any one guide how to set it ? or any tool to set tcp parameters

I have asked this question on stackoverflow [[here]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094114/how-to-enable-disable-tcp-delayed-ack-parameter-on-linux) earlier but as per their suggestion I am reposting it on serverfault.com

Comment: I dont want to use TCP_QUICKACK or TCP_NODELAY

Answer (score 2):

The only Linux kernel I know of which exposes Delayed ACK as a system-wide tunable is Red Hat MRG 2.0. You could use CentOS with the `kernel-rt` package which gets you the same thing for free.

If you want to patch your own kernel [here](http://www.spinics.net/lists/netdev/msg236586.html#.Uq7WrsO84-U) is a start.

The Novell knowledgebase article you have posted is over 10 years old and is for Novell NetWare, not Linux.

Everyone else in the world is using `TCP_QUICKACK`, you can too.